# make button disappear when don't move mouse and appear when move it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I would like to have my button only appear when the mouse is moved, and otherwise not be seen. It is fixed positioned.

Comment: Please show your code

Comment: Did you try using "onmousemove" or "mousemove()" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```js
var justHidden = false;

$(document).ready(function() {
    var j;
    $(document).mousemove(function() {
        if (!justHidden) {
            justHidden = false;
            clearTimeout(j);
            $('.btn').removeClass('hidden');
            j = setTimeout('hide();', 1000);
        }
    });
});

function hide() {
    $('.btn').addClass('hidden');
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
  <body>
    <button class="btn hidden">Click me</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: is there a way to hide the buttons in a slowly fading manner?

Comment: @user4381753 Yes, change CSS to:
.btn {
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity .3s ease-in-out;
}
.hidden {
  opacity: 0;
}

Answer (score 0):

**Html Code :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>      
<body>

    <button id="btn1">Click me</button>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Js Code :**

```
 <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#btn1").on({
            mouseenter: function(){
                $(this).show();
            },  
            mouseleave: function(){
                $(this).hide();
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the button on mouse move, you can use following example-

1.Write the below code in your HTML file:

```
<button id='hide_button'>Button</button>
```

2.And add the below code in your JS file:

```
var timeout = null
$(document).on('mousemove', function() {
    if (timeout !== null) {
       $('#hide_button').hide();
        clearTimeout(timeout);
    }

    timeout = setTimeout(function() {
         $('#hide_button').show();
    }, 3000);
});
```

The Button will be hidden while the mouse is moving. Else, you should see the button after 3 seconds of mouse inactivity.
You can check this example using this link- http://jsfiddle.net/bnfsukhx/